# Why static block is not executed first when we call static final variable

Tags: java

```
class Test4 {
     public static void main(String as[]) {
         System.out.println(Hello.x); 
     }

}

class Hello {
    final static int x=10;
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello");                
    }
}
```

Output: `10`

Why it is not printing `Hello` as per my knowledge if we call static variable then first class is loaded and when class will be loaded then first it should execute static block then static variable will be sent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A static initializer block is executed when the class that contains it is initialized - which is normally when the class is loaded.

You would say that the JVM should load and initialize class `Hello` when you access `Hello.x` in class `Test4`. However, that doesn't happen here, because this is a special case.

`static final` constants are inlined by the compiler - which means that when this code is compiled, the `Hello.x` in the `main` method is replaced at compilation time by the value of the constant, which is `10`. Essentially, your code compiles to the same byte code as when you would compile this:

```
class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(10); // Inlined constant value here!
    }
}

class Hello {
    final static int x = 10;
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello");                
    }
}
```

Note that class `Test4` doesn't really access class `Hello` in this case - so class `Hello` is not loaded and the static initializer is not executed when you run `Test4`.

Comment: class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(10); // Inlined constant value here!
    }
}

class Hello {
    final static int x;
    static {
          x=10; System.out.println("Hello");                
    }
}

Comment: a/c to your concept, in this case also compiler will replace Hello.x with 10 and result will be 10.  But actual result is Hello 10

Comment: @DEEPAKKUMAR You slightly modified my code and therefore what I described above doesn't hold anymore.